# Strange UIScrollView behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

Because this problem is hard to describe, I've created a GitHub repo for a bare bones Xcode project [here](https://github.com/doovers/uiscrollview-bug) to demo the problem.

In a nutshell, I have a signup form in a `UIScrollView` which in a certain scenario makes the view semi-unresponsive (i.e. buttons actions not firing). The steps to reproduce are to manually select each `UITextField` and press 'Done' button on the keyboard to dismiss it for the last field. This sequence of user inputs seems to be the only way to reproduce the behaviour.

I've managed to solve the issue with a hack to reset the content offset of the scroll view in response to the `keyboardWillHide` notification but this results in a visible jump in the scroll position.

Anyone have any ideas on what's happening here? I've spent 2 days investigating this and I'm at a total loss as to what's happening. Would really appreciate some help here!

Comment: Irrelevant, but you do not need a `break` at the end of every `case` of a `switch`. This is Swift, not C.

Comment: @matt Lol fair point :)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can you give better instructions?

Comment: @matt I've updated the instructions on GitHub, I hope that's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Can't reproduce any issue. See my answer below (and watch my YouTube video). It's working okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise the following:

- Get rid of the "center scrollview" stuff. This is just wrong. If you want to center your content vertically, put it in a content view and use autolayout.
- Detect UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, not WillChange.
- Get rid of your "hack to make it work".

Comment: I've posted a YouTube video showing that it works fine for me when I make those changes: https://youtu.be/ZQqJ6-PfR6k

Comment: I also followed your new instructions but I still can't reproduce a problem. The Signup button still works.

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean. Yes the button is still responsive but it is not firing the action. There should be a print statement in the console after tapping it. Also, the text fields become unresponsive.

Comment: The print statement does appear. And the text fields do not become unresponsive. Really.  Do I need to remake the video to prove it to you?

Comment: Made another video https://youtu.be/9zkPwkNlTtc No problem. Really. That's all for today, off to bed.

Comment: No I believe you! I really can't explain what is going on then because it is doing what I say in multiple simulators and devices for me! I'll record a video to demonstrate...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mb-8jRzF0mw

Comment: Okay but I don't know what your code looks like now. My answer tells you to make certain changes. Make them! When you do, there's no issue, and my videos prove it.

Comment: Well, it turns out that despite cleaning the project, deleting derived data, restarting Xcode and subsequently (in desperation) my macbook, then recreating the view in a blank project, the problem still remained but when I looked again today my original code worked fine! Very weird but at least I made the video to prove it! Thanks for the help anyway though, much appreciated!

Comment: Oops I thought I had! Seems I upvoted instead!

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind unresponsive of your view is like content size is not properly set. Set the `background color of view` which you have put inside the scrollview. Also set the `background color of scrollview`. You will get the idea, some of the textfield are `out of contentsize` area. That's why it becomes unresponsive.

Let me know if you still facing the issue. It will solve your problem :-)

**EDIT**

Here you go with the working code that you want:-)

https://www.sendspace.com/file/k5v9uy

Comment: Your sign in and signup buttons are below the contentsize area.

Comment: What size screen are you testing on? I'm using iPhone 6 and it seems fine to me?

Comment: I am talking about general. Can you show me your storyboard? I can guide you what you have done wrong.

Comment: Thanks! There is a link to the project in my question

Comment: Ohh..I got it. Let me check.

Comment: Your signup action not working right?

Comment: I have checked in iPhone5s and working by some constraint modification.

Comment: See this video for demo https://youtube.com/watch?v=Mb-8jRzF0mw and use iphone 6s simulator

Comment: check code. Let me know working or not at your end. I have tested in all simulator. It's working fine at my end.

Comment: Update your code in github if it's work. Because link I have provided will expire after few days. Also replace in my answer.

Comment: I don't see any changes in that project. What did you modify?

Comment: In story board I have modified constraint for contentview

Comment: EqualHeight constraint.

Comment: You got the solution?

Comment: I did actually but it turns out the original project was fine all along! I tried everything including starting from scratch but all of a sudden the problem disappeared! Very weird problem but thank you for your help anyway it was much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Whenever a `UITextField` becomes first responder, `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` will invoke. So it will be very difficult to calculate the content offset in `UITextFieldDelegate`. You may think the keyboard is always there, but it changes when you change the responder. `UITableViewController` can solve your problem automatically.